# How would this country react to an unprepared war?

Tags: warfare

1. My country is located on 3 islands in the middle of the ocean.
2. Its military/police force consists of a few special forces units.
3. The tech level is mostly the same as today for the attacker with about 30 year advantage for defense.
4. The cities are base mostly inland except for 4 coastal cities.
5. There are 27 cities distributed on the 3 islands.
6. Its capital (also the HQ of the S.F.) is centered around the other 3 islands.
7. Nukes aren't a threat to the country but it can't use them either.
8. The war proposal was made peacefully (It didn't declare war with an invasion) and it has 2 months to prepare.

**Edit**

9. The cities are mostly underground with connections to the other cities and islands (with the standard Lock down in case of quarantining)

Comment: These must be massive islands if there are 23 identifiable, inland cities on 3 islands. Who's going to war with whom? Cities vs. cities? Islands vs. islands? Cities/islands vs. external nation?

Comment: There is a contradiction: the country is unprepared but receive a warning of two months to prepare for war. That is plenty of time to prepare and most countries do not have that luxury (ex: Pearl Harbor)

Comment: What country would give is opposant a 2 month notice anyway ?

Comment: What is the mindset of the country?  As a general rule, when a country is unprepared for war, they get overrun, stripping everything away until the naked mindset behind the people gets exposed.  The defensive effort is usually built on kernels of that mindset.

Comment: An underground city on an island will be mostly below sea level. I hope the people there are good swimmers.

Comment: @KSmarts huh good attack strategy

Comment: Also what does the "S.F." mean (in #6)?

Comment: @wposeyjr - special forces I'd assume.    JKK1111 - Islands don't have much for water ways and tend to prohibit inland cities of any form.  They are usually volcanic if situation in the middle of an ocean, which tends to mean the center of the island is an uninhabitable volcano.  Inland trade routes are difficult, so everything is situated on the coast and transported via ships.  If you are going larger island...remember Australia has around 85% of it's population concentrated on the coastline.  Underground on an island is a little strange as well

Comment: @Vincent U.s. were not expecting Pearl Harbour but due to WW2 in Europe they were prepared for war, they just were not sure when it would start. This would seem a more likely situation here, a rival nation is becoming threatening so they prepare for war but don't know  when they will be invaded.

Answer (score 8):

Since you don't specify the tech level or the military force levels of the enemy, there is no way to give a good answer. But let's say that the enemy has WWII tech levels, and has naval, air and marine forces adequate for the job. Meanwhile, our defenders have current tech levels and (as you say) no military to speak of. In that case the answer is straightforward.

Pretty much the response is the old couplet:

"When uncertain or in doubt,
Run in circles, scream and shout."

Or, if you prefer one-word answers, surrender.

Since the country apparently has no naval or air forces, there will be almost nothing that can be done to resist the invasion force when it arrives. Conceivably the nation could convert its civilian aircraft to kamikazis by loading them with explosives, but that would pretty much require the existence of an explosives industry. Furthermore, even WWII anti-aircraft defenses will do pretty well against civilian aircraft, unless the pilots are very good at low-level flying and have an excellent radar/communications net to guide them on their terminal run. And preemptive strikes on airports will cut way down on the number of kamikazis which can be launched, since in the absence of AA defenses for the airports such strikes can be placed with some precision.

You just don't build an army in two months, and you don't build up the equipment needed for that army in two months, either. Warships, combat aircraft and artillery are long-lead, specialty goods.

Your best bet would be providing small arms to the populace and providing for a guerrilla resistance after the occupation, using your SF troops as cadres. This will have the problem that there is no way to select for effective leadership at any level until the shooting starts - the defenders apparently don't do violence much, and peacetime armies traditionally have to undergo a steep learning curve when they transition to combat operations. (Quick paraphrase: peacetime militaries tend to promote a lot of people for the wrong reasons.)

Comment: This makes for a good story and i edited it to include the tech level

Comment: @JKK1111 - While I appreciate the selection, it's generally a good idea to wait at least 24 hours to select a winner. Given a little more time, someone may provide an even better answer. 1 hour just isn't enough.

Answer (score 3):

The standard approach would be try and prevent enemy from landing as possible, so water mines, land mines on beaches, beefing up air defenses and/or air force. The most accessible landing areas should also be targetable by artillery. There should be shore based anti-ship missiles around important passages.

However the most important thing would be to stock up on *everything*, islands can't be resource self sufficient and anyone fighting them can blockade supply routes relatively easily, so fuel, ammo food etc, has to stocked up for a long haul.

Comment: And how would they stock up on stuff they don't make? They only have 2 months to get their production lines going.

Comment: Import as much as they can, I'm not saying they'll do well in this setup, I'm just trying to think of ways that would improve the situation